# method_missing equivalent in R

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

Is there an equivalent to method_missing for R?
In other words, is it possible to intercept a call to an nonexistent method on an object and do something with it?
Examples for all types of classes would be great (S3, S4, reference classes).
What I want to do is build an object `a` so that something like `a$b` would be possible without having to define b explicitly.

Edit: This is approximately how I would like my object to behave:

```
setClass("myClass", representation(url = "character"))
a <- new("myClass", url = "http://www.example.com")
a$b$c
# => 'http://www.example.com/b/c'
```

This is S4 classes but any implementation suggestion is welcome.

regards Oskar

Comment: You might want to include whether you are using S3, S4 or reference classes (or if you're asking about all three).

Comment: Seems like a reproducible example would help here.  I assume you want something more sophisticated than just checking the output of `methods('foo')` for `foo.bar`?

Comment: Now I'm confused.  `a$b` has little to do with methods....

Comment: If not method, what would be a better name for what b is to a in `a$b`?

Comment: Ah maybe you're referring to an operator `$` that has a method for whatever class `a` is.  Maybe best to keep this simple and deal with functions not operators (the latter is just a function with certain conventions in R, but it will be confusinger).

Comment: Yeah, this question needs _a lot_ of clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the access `a$b`, **yes**, this is possible – if messy. The reason is that `$` is just an operator that we can redefine.

The default definition can be retrieved as follows:

```
> `$`
.Primitive("$")
```

It’s <del>easy enough</del> *possible* to change this so that we first test whether the `b` in `a$b` actually exists. Here’s a rough outline (but *only* a rough outline, see below):

```
`$` <- function (a, b) {
    if (exists(as.character(substitute(b)), where = a))
        .Primitive("$")(a, b)
    else
        methodMissing(as.character(substitute(a)), as.character(substitute(b)))
}
```

… now we just need to supply `methodMissing`:

```
methodMissing <- function (a, b)
    cat(sprintf('Requested missing %s on %s\n', b, a))
```

… and we can use it:

```
> foo <- list(bar = 'Hello')
> foo$bar
[1] "hello"
> foo$baz
Requested missing baz on foo
```

However, note that this breaks in interesting ways for other types – for instance, it no longer works with data frames:

```
> cars$speed
NULL
```

I don’t know whether it’s trivial to fix this – it’s *not* enough to test for `is.list(a)`, for instance – so proceed with caution.

The solutions for S3 and S4 are left as an exercise for the reader (actually, I have no clue – I don’t use S4 and rarely use S3).

Answer (score 0):

[tryCatch](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912) should be the equivalent of method_missing, if I've understood your question properly:

```
tryCatch(foo(options, named=option1,...), EXCEPTION-CLAUSE-HERE)
```